# React Hook hover state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

basically i have 3 cards that will need a hover effect and i thought about doing it with useState, but as there are 3 cards I can't use the same state for 3
in this case I would have to create 3 states one for each card to apply my hover effect to my div and my h1

if my h1 is on hover i aplly css on my bg and my h1 and

code:

```
const DivCar = () => {
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);
  console.log(isHover);
  return (
    <Carousel arrows slidesPerScroll={1} slidesPerPage={3} centered infinite>
      <Styled.CardCarousel background={TestBG} isHover={isHover}>
        <div
          className="Bg"
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
        ></div>
        <div className="headerH3">
          <h3
            onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}
          >
            <a href="xd4">
              Rede de esgotos é desobstruída no Pontalzinho Pontalzinho.
            </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardCarousel>
      <Styled.CardCarousel background={TestBG2} isHover={isHover}>
        <div
          className="Bg"
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
        ></div>
        <div className="headerH3">
          <h3
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
          >
            <a href="xd4">.</a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardCarousel>
      <Styled.CardCarousel background={TestBG} isHover={isHover}>
        <div
          className="Bg"
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
        ></div>
        <div className="headerH3">
          <h3
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
          >
            <a href="xd4">.</a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardCarousel>
      <Styled.CardCarousel background={TestBG2} isHover={isHover}>
        <div
          className="Bg"
          onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
        ></div>
        <div className="headerH3">
          <h3
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
          >
            <a href="xd4">.</a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardCarousel>
    </Carousel>
  );
};
```

I wonder if there is any better option besides having to create 1 state for each card

(because if only one is left) when one is hovering the effect will go to all cards and not just to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is you can store json in one state, and create a separate function that takes card name to update, for example;

```js
const [hoveredCards, setHoveredCards] = useState(
  {
    card1: false,
    card2: false,
    card3: false,
  }
);


const updateHoveredCards = (cardName, value) => {
   let existingValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(hoveredCards))
   existingValues[cardName] = value
   setHoveredCards(existingValues)
} 

return (
    <Carousel arrows slidesPerScroll={1} slidesPerPage={3} centered infinite>
      <Styled.CardCarousel background={TestBG} isHover={hoveredCards.card1}>
        <div
          className="Bg"
          onMouseEnter={() => updateHoveredCards("card1", true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => updateHoveredCards("card2", false)}
        ></div>
        <div className="headerH3">
          <h3
            onMouseOver={() => updateHoveredCards("card1", true)}
            onMouseOut={() => updateHoveredCards("card2", false)}
          >
            <a href="xd4">
              Rede de esgotos é desobstruída no Pontalzinho Pontalzinho.
            </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </Styled.CardCarousel>
      ...
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the useState logic inside the **Styled.CardCarousel**?
And if you're not the owner of **Styled.CardCarousel** just create on component wrapping it to contain the state.

Comment: styled.cardcarousel is div with styled components.